# jQuery Remove table rows without removing the rowspan column

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a table with rowspan as a starting column.the table has a delete button at the end of each row.when the button is clicked, the corresponding row will be deleted. Code for the table is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  
 <table border="1" >
    <tr> <td rowspan="6" > First Section </td><td> Row 1-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 1 - Col 2 </td>  <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 2-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 2 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 3-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 3 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 4-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 4 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 5-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 5 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 6-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 6 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
 </table>
    
  
  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.remove').on('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the delete buttons in the rows other than the first row it works fine, but if I click on the delete button for the first row it also delete the rowspan column.

**How to delete the first row without deleting the rowspan column?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change structure of your table and your code will work look at fiddle

```
<table border="1" >
    <tr> <td rowspan="6" > First Section </td> </tr>
    <tr><td>
      <table  border="1">
        <tr>
        <td> Row 1-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 1 - Col 2 </td>  <td class="remove" > Delete </td></tr>
          <tr> <td> Row 2-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 2 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 3-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 3 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 4-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 4 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 5-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 5 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 6-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 6 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> 
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td></tr>
 </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oktnr85k/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).closest("tr").index() == 0) {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:nth-child(1))").remove();
  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6"> First Section </td>
    <td> Row 1-Col 1 </td>
    <td> Row 1 - Col 2 </td>
    <td class="remove"> Delete </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Row 2-Col 1 </td>
    <td> Row 2 - Col 2 </td>
    <td class="remove"> Delete </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Row 3-Col 1 </td>
    <td> Row 3 - Col 2 </td>
    <td class="remove"> Delete </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Row 4-Col 1 </td>
    <td> Row 4 - Col 2 </td>
    <td class="remove"> Delete </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Row 5-Col 1 </td>
    <td> Row 5 - Col 2 </td>
    <td class="remove"> Delete </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Row 6-Col 1 </td>
    <td> Row 6 - Col 2 </td>
    <td class="remove"> Delete </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

1. check if the clicked row is first then remove all other td except first
2. if not first remove entire tr

Answer (score 0):

Use `siblings()` and `not()` selector. Give some class for `rowspan` to use not .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  
 <table border="1" >
    <tr> <td rowspan="6" class='test' > First Section </td><td> Row 1-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 1 - Col 2 </td>  <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 2-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 2 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 3-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 3 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 4-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 4 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 5-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 5 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Row 6-Col 1 </td> <td> Row 6 - Col 2 </td> <td class="remove" > Delete </td> </tr>
 </table>
    
  
  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.remove').on('click',function(){
            $(this).siblings().not('.test').remove();
            $(this).remove();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```